# How would the Polar Express have been able to go back the same way with the ice on the lake having been cracked?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-polar-express

In "The Polar Express", how would the Train have been able to go back the same way with the Ice on the Frozen Lake having cracked?

Comment: Maybe it refroze?

Comment: There's nothing in the [official novelisation of the film](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Polar-Express-Trip-North-Pole/dp/061847790X) and the script just says "They set off" and then cuts to him sitting glumly as they pass his friend's house